# Apply formatting to all subplots in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

When plotting 3 pandas dataframe with different time resolution (hourly, daily, monthly) in Jupyter Notebook, I would like to apply a consistent format to all three subplots showing only month and not year (i.e. Jan, Feb, Mar, and not Jan 2010, Feb 2010, Mar 2010).

Question: how to apply the formatting across all subplots?

Import libraries

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

Create 3 dataframes

```
hourly = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.rand(24*365)}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31 23:00', freq='1H'))
daily = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.rand(365)}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31 23:00', freq='1D'))
monthly = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.rand(12)}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31 23:00', freq='1M'))
```

Plot and apply formatting to three subplots

```
def plot2(hourly, daily, monthly):
    f, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex = False, figsize=(16, 14))
    hourly[['val']].plot(ax=ax[0], legend=False)
    daily[['val']].plot(ax=ax[1], legend=False)
    monthly[['val']].plot(ax=ax[2], legend=False)

    for axA in ax:
        month = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()
        monthFmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b')
        axA.xaxis.set_major_locator(month)
        axA.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthFmt)
        for item in axA.get_xticklabels():
            item.set_rotation(0)

    sns.despine()
    plt.tight_layout()
    return f, ax

plot2(hourly, daily, monthly)
```

The resulting figure shows the desired formatting for the second and third plots, but not the first plot. 
[Figure showing the first plot is not formatted properly, but the second and third plots are formatted properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtTCA.png)

I am using Python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like pandas has some problems. Using matplolib directly works better:

```
def plot2(hourly, daily, monthly):
    f, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex = False, figsize=(16, 14))
    ax[0].plot(hourly.index, hourly[['val']])
    ax[1].plot(daily.index, daily[['val']])
    ax[2].plot(monthly.index, monthly[['val']])

    for axA in ax[::-1]:
        month = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()
        monthFmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b')
        axA.xaxis.set_major_locator(month)
        axA.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthFmt)
        for item in axA.get_xticklabels():
            item.set_rotation(0)

    sns.despine()
    plt.tight_layout()
    return f, ax
```

[image]

Comment: With no special formatting, the figure still show Jan 2010 on all three subplots. For this application, I would like to only showing the month and not showing the year.

Comment: Should be better now.